# Filter Pandas Dataframe with specific time of day or hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I have a very large dataset : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption

It contains around 2.5M rows.
The Pandas dataframe index is a timestamp and then it has several columns.

I want to filter the dataset so I only see, for instance, 9AM (09:00:00) rows only for all years (around 1400 rows aprox ->365*4)

[image: The Pandas dataframe looks like this]

I have tried this:

`dataset.groupby(dataset.index.hour == '09:00:00')`

But it doesn't work. I have also tried without sucess this:

`dataset['09:00:00']`

Thanks

Comment: Hi @marc, when you say ("But it doesn't work") what exactly do you get back? An empty dataframe? Some of the results you want, but not all of them? More results than you expected? A Mix?

Comment: Hi LeoRochael, I was getting an error message. Peter has solved the problem. The mistake was using `==09:00:00` instead of using `== 9`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two attempts are close! It should be possible to select desired rows using a boolean mask as follows:

```
dataset[dataset.index.hour == 9]
```